# Plotting points from point data cloud

Tags: python, pandas, computer-vision, nan, point-clouds

I am trying to plot points from point cloud data but on diagram it is shown just as 2 points. The point cloud data has 171 rows and 224 combinations of 5 parameters `(x,y,z,intensity,noise)`.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


df1 = pd.read_csv('cloud.txt',delimiter='\t',skipinitialspace=True)
df1.dropna() #mojpoklusaj
print(type(df1))

pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
df1 = df1.apply (pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')
#cloud.dropna()
df1.fillna(0,axis=0,inplace=True)
print(len(df1.columns))

x_list = []
y_list = []
z_list = []


for x in range(1,1121):    
converted_list = df1.iloc[:,x].tolist()
for index in range(len(converted_list)):
point = converted_list[index]
#np.log(point**10)
modul = index % 5 
if modul == 0:
    x_list.append(point)
elif modul == 1:
    y_list.append(point)
elif modul == 2:
    z_list.append(point)
else:
    continue


#df = pd.DataFrame(data) 
#print(type(df))
#print(df1)
#d_list = list(df1.columns.values)
#print(d_list)
#print(type(df1))
#x = d_list[0]
#y = df1[1].tolist()
#z = df1[2].tolist()

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(projection='3d')


ax.scatter( z_list, y_list, x_list, c=z_list, cmap='viridis', linewidth=1)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Could you share with us cloud.txt file?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to upload that here on the page, but here is link for download from mediafire: https://www.mediafire.com/file/9sbhhro8b15cx2k/cloud.txt/file

Comment: @Worldmaster I shared it above